# Why is my request property getting an empty array when using content type application/json-patch+json?

Tags: rest, http-patch

I have a PATCH operation that takes a request body of content type `application/json-patch+json`. Example request body:

```
{
  "operations": [
    {
      "op": "remove",
      "path": "/blah"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I hit the API, my server is getting an empty `operations` array in the request body. However if I switch the accepted content type to `application/json` and use that for the request, I get a populated array.

I have tried not having an `operations` property and just an array but that causes an error with our API validator.

Does anyone know what it is about `application/json-patch+json` that's causing this?

Comment: If you validated you sent this literally to the server, and you're not seeing this server-side then something is wrong on the server. No one will be able to guess without more context.